# How to implement responsive table in Grails?

Tags: user-interface, jquery-ui, button, grails

How to implement a table cell in Grails that will have a button and pressing it will change data in a cell of the same row? Lets say table has only id, assignment, accepted (yes, no) fields. The value of accepted is by default no and when you click on Accept button it changes to yes.

Should I use Grails UI Data Table or jQuery Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `submitToRemote` button and update the current table row using the `update` tag. E.g: in your `index.gsp`:

```
<table>
<g:each in="${yourDataList}" var="data">
<tr id="dataRow${data.id}">
    <g:render template="tableRow" />
</tr>
</g:each>
</table>
```

Where your _tableRow.gsp template is something like:

```
<td>${data.id}</td>
<td>${data.booleanValue}</td>
<td><g:submitToRemote action="updateAction" id="${data.id}" update="dataRow${data.id}" /></td>
```

Note the attribute value of `update` is the same as of the `<tr>` from `index.gsp`. 
Your controller has an action `updateAction`:

```
def updateAction = {
    Data data = Data.get(params.id)

    // your business logic
    data.booleanValue = false;

    data.save(flush: true);

    render(template: "tableRow", model: [data: data]);
}
```

There are obviously other possibilities, but this might be an option for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Why are you rendering template in the view? Shouldnt it just be done in the controller action? And isnt the g:submitToRemote tag update property just for defining the div youre changing?

Comment: I tried different combinations of youre suggestion but none worked. I've managged to render a view properly, but button wasn't responsive.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have understood you. The piece of codes just shows, how to make a table, where the user can execute some actions on each row (e.g. accept a task), and depending on the action something on the page is changed (in this case the table row is reloaded from the server and the gsp logic handles your change then: change the button text for example).